# Rest best practice: when to return 404 not found

Tags: web-services, rest

If I have the following rest call:

```
GET /items/{id}/subitems
```

Should we return the following in these scenarios?:

1. If `{id}` not found, should we return `404 Not Found`?
2. If `{id}` found but not subitems found, should we return `200 Ok` and an empty array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me the answer is **yes** for both questions.

REST is about resources. If resource with given ID hasn't been found, then `404 Not Found` is the most appropriate response status.

But at the same time,  `GET /items/{id}/subitems/{subitem-id}` should definitely return the `HTTP 404` if subitem with given id doesn't exist.